# Deploy VSTO application in visual studio windows application

Tags: vsto

I have created a VSTO application using office 2005 & visual studio 2005 professional.I found there a setup folder.While i am running the *.exe file in client machine,it giving me error."An add-in could not be found or could not be loaded."

Comment: This is an Urgent.Please solve this.Thanks all in advance.

Comment: At a guess with this little information, I'd say this was probably caused by missing dependancies - in this case version 1 of VSTO runtime and .NET 2.0 framework (+ with that version you need the Office 2003 PIAs installed) user incorrectly refers to it as Office 2005.

Answer (score 1):

What is the architecture of the client machine?

If Vista: do you have the UAC (Security Dialog) disabled?

Also check in the Registry if the Path to the Manifest File is correct.

Is it loading the right Framework Version?

Are you using the Publish feature, or are you trying to create your own MSI?

You need to do some debugging on your side to have this sorted maybe:

1. Try to uninstall VSTO SE completely and install it again.
2. Create a new VSTO add-in without any additional code and run it.
3. Evaluate what happens and perform actions accordingly